# Building a static local website using Rmarkdown: step by step procedure

Tags: r

I am trying to understand the procedure of building a static local website using [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and `Rmarkdown`. I am aware of a [Rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#creating-a-website) website where the procedure is outlined, but unfortunately I do not understand the steps.

Does anybody here have some experience in building a static local website and would be so kind as to describe the procedure in more detail?

Comment: Not sure that a web development question belongs on this site. R is popular here, but this question does not seem to be about doing data science.

Comment: The question is linked to reproducible research in data science as one can seamlessly integrate R source code with markdown and produce html output.

Comment: I agree with the OP - this question is more about reproducible research than web development and has significant data science component. Therefore, it definitely belongs to this site in my book.

Comment: If its really about reproducible research it needs more explanation. As it stands its just "How do I build a static web site using R?". Close.

Comment: I think it's on-topic but merely too broad. A better question would identify what has been tried, and what specifically went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most things, related to **R**, there are **many approaches** to solve a problem, sometimes too many, I would say. The task of building a static website, using *RMarkdown*, is not an exception.

One of the best, albeit somewhat brief, sets of workflows on the topic include the following one by Daniel Wollschlaeger, which includes [this workflow](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/rerWorkflowJN.html), based on *R*, *nanoc* and *Jekyll*, as well as [this workflow](http://www.uni-kiel.de/psychologie/rexrepos/posts/rerWorkflowWP.html), based on *R* and *WordPress*. Another good workflow is [this one](http://jason.bryer.org/posts/2012-12-10/Markdown_Jekyll_R_for_Blogging.html) by Jason Bryer, which is focused on *R(Markdown)*, *Jekyll* and *GitHub Pages*.

Not everyone likes *GitHub Pages*, *Jekyll*, *Octopress* and *Ruby*, so some people came up with *alternative solutions*. For example, [this workflow](http://www.znmeb.mobi/stories/blogging-with-rstudio-and-nikola.html) by Edward Borasky is based on *R* and, for a static website generator, on *Python*-based *Nicola* (instead of *Ruby*-based *Jekyll* or *nanoc*). Speaking about **static website generators**, there are tons of them, in various programming languages, so, if you want to experiment, check [this amazing website](http://staticsitegenerators.net), listing almost all of them. Almost, because some are missing - for example, *Samantha* and *Ghost*, listed [here](http://ropensci.github.io/reproducibility-guide/sections/tools).

Some other interesting workflows include [this one](http://joshualande.com/jekyll-github-pages-poole) by Joshua Lande, which is based on Jekyll and GitHub Pages, but includes some nice examples of customization for integrating a website with Disqus, Google Analytics and Twitter as well as getting custom URL for the site and more.

Those who want a **pure R-based static site solution**, now have some options, including `rsmith` (https://github.com/hadley/rsmith), a static site generator by Hadley Wickham, and `Poirot` (https://github.com/ramnathv/poirot), a static site generator by Ramnath Vaidyanathan.

Finally, I would like to mention an [interesting project](http://notebook.madsenlab.org/labnotebook.html) (from an **open science** perspective) that I recently ran across - an open source software by Mark Madsen for a *lab notebook static site*, which is based on *GitHub Pages* and *Jekyll*, but also supports *pandoc*, *R*, *RMarkdown* and *knitr*.

Comment: I was looking for a pure R-based solutions actually. I will explore the ones that you pointed at. Thank you.

Comment: @MihaTrošt: My pleasure - I'm glad to help.